# Using Ninject as the IoC for Caliburn Micro for WP7

Tags: ninject, caliburn.micro, common-service-locator

I'm trying to use Ninject as the IOC container for Caliburn Micro for WP7.1 Mango.
The only post I found for [doing this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=ninject%20cm%20wp7&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2011/07/08/using-ninject-with-commonservicelocator-with-caliburn-micro-on-wp7.aspx&ei=CU8vT-ODEI_MiQLozoCoCg&usg=AFQjCNGQ6juMkh2pLcjd4RhcOPBOC6zvKw) creates the NinjectServiceLocator and sets that as the provider on the ServiceLocator.
Questions:
1) NinjectServiceLocator defined in "CommonServiceLocator.NinjectAdapter" assembly depends on 
v 1.0.0.0 of "Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation". Has Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation been ported to WP 7.1?

2) I tried to install "ninject.wp7" using nuget but it does not install witht the following error:
**Could not install package 'Ninject.WP7 2.2.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targ
ets 'Silverlight,Version=v4.0,Profile=WindowsPhone71', but the package does not contain any assembly references that are compatible with that framework**

Are there an workarounds to make this work on Mango. I'm really looking for using an IOC with CM that will allow me to scan assemblies to register viewmodels intead of hand wiring each type in the default SimpleContainer.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ninject 3.0.0-rc3 which has support for WP 7.1

```
Install-Package Ninject -pre
```